# Function not returning the expected result

Tags: javascript

I have written a function to search an array and log a number(x) if it is found. The code below works as expected and 1 is logged.

```
let myArr = [54, 23, 499, 342, 1, 44];
let x = 1;

let searchNumber = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(ele => {
    if (ele == x) {
      console.log(ele);
    }
  })
};

searchNumber(myArr);
```

I'd like to now return the number that I assign to variable x. Expecting y to be assigned 499 but when I log y it returns undefined. Where am I going wrong?

```
let myArr = [54, 23, 499, 342, 1, 44];
let x = 499;

let searchNumber = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(ele => {
    if (ele == x) {
      return ele;
    }
  })
};

let y = searchNumber(myArr);
```

Comment: you can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return the first element that satisfies a condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the placement of the return statement, it is actually within the arrow function being called for each element (`ele => {...}`). No value is actually being returned from the scope of the function `searchNumber`.

Try creating a variable in the scope of `searchNumber` and modifying it from `arr.forEach()` instead:

```js
let myArr = [54, 23, 499, 342, 1, 44];
let x = 499;

let searchNumber = (arr) => {
    let val = null;
    arr.forEach(ele => {
        if (ele == x) {
            val = ele;
        }
    });
   return val;
};

let y = searchNumber(myArr);
```

Answer (score 6):

`return ele` inside `forEach` callback is not the `return` of the `searchNumber` function.

`forEach` executes a provided function once for each array element so `return ele` inside that will act like `return` to that provided function inside `forEach`.

It does not repesent the `return` to the main function.

In this case, it's better to use `for` loop.

```js
let myArr = [54, 23, 499, 342, 1, 44];
let x = 499;

let searchNumber = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i] == x) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
};

let y = searchNumber(myArr);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thanks Derek.W for your explanation.

Comment: Can you approve my answer if that helped?

Comment: sorry not that used to using the forums. My issue was with misunderstanding the use of .forEach(), I was avaoiding using a for loop in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot break (exit) a forEach, it will iterate all elements.
the array.find() should do the trick https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp
or array.findIndex() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp

Answer (score 2):

[`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return the matching element:

```js
let myArr = [54, 23, 499, 342, 1, 44];
let x = 499;

let searchNumber = (arr) => arr.find(ele => ele == x);

let y = searchNumber(myArr);

console.log(y);
```

Comment: This is a better way to do it, thanks for pointing that out @Majed Badawi.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking here is probably the find function.

```
let searchNumber = (arr) => arr.find(e => e === x);

let y = searchNumber(myArr);
```